# My smartphone does not recognize headphones

Tags: lumia, 8.1

I received a Nokia Numia 635 (T-Mobile) yesterday for my birthday. I've since noticed that when I try to use headphones with it, the phone doesn't "detect" them, i.e., it keeps using the speakers. I'm using a pair of Skullcandy Hesh 2 headphones. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I have a set of sony headphones with a mic and the mic regularly doesn't work. I think that it has issues with sony products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution - A simple restart fixed it.

EDIT: The phone was brand new when I posted this, and I'm going with the assumption that it had something to do with the updates needing a restart to finalize.

Comment: Does your Hesh 2 have a microphone? Headphones which doesn't have a mic won't work with Lumia phones. Check with a headset which is having a mic, preferably a Nokia headset.

Comment: Standard headphones work with my Lumia...

Comment: ^ Yeah. Mine don't have a mic and they work fine now with my phone. It must have been something with the software updates that required another restart.

Comment: From my experience, I've connected the default Nokia headset to my Lumia 630 and I could hear the sound well. But I connected a SoundMAGIC E10 headphone to my phone which doesn't have a mic, thinking that I could get the best sound experience, it isn't working or recognizing. Later then I tried a Sony MDR- XB30EX Extra-Bass Stereo Headphone without mic and it also disappointed me. But then I tried connecting a Samsung headset which is having a mic packed with Samsung Galaxy S2 and it was working. From this I understood that headphones without mic doesn't work with Lumia. That's what I said!

Comment: I just found that both the answers have been down voted. The answer which I said is what my experience! Let me know if anyone have the same problem as mine!

Comment: I have the same problem. After about half an hour of trying to get them to work they work. But when I remove the headphones it keeps saying that there are still headphones