# My nokia Lumia 520 wont accept earphones

Tags: lumia-520

I got my Nokia Lumia 520 5 months ago and I has been fine until now. Any headphones/earphones I plug in are not being accepted and music just plays out normally without earphones... I tried restarting my phone but it didn't work. Please help

Comment: Was it damaged physically somehow ? Since when are you facing this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/5690/106

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a soft reset and also double check your headphones work on another device.
If that doesn't work you'll probably have to send in your phone to Nokia / Microsoft services. However before you do that, also try a hard reset.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes pocket lint can get in the headphone jack and needs to be removed. Use a flashlight to look down the hole. You should be able to tell that there is something in there or not.

If it is some pocket lint and if you are *really* careful, you can insert a thin paperclip to remove any fuzz.